# Dynamic SQL INSERT Takes 30x Longer than it Should

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

We have built a C# .NET system that can be used to create data warehouses. This system takes selected databases and run a script against these databases to create a combined database/warehouse.

Now, I have three databases to be compiled into a single database and I am copying two tables from each (table [XI] and table [XII] - which have a one to many relationship, but have no constraints set up at the time of the copy/`INSERT INTO`). The figures for the script to run and the relevant sizes for each table are below:

The executed script consists of 30 SQL queries.

1. **DatabaseA**:

   ```
   Table [XI]  29,026 Rows (size 20,128Kb).
   Table [XII] 531,958 Rows (size 50,168Kb).
   Time taken for entire script: 1.51s.
   ```
2. **DatabaseB**:

   ```
   Table [XI]  117,877 Rows (size 17,000Kb).
   Table [XII] 4,000,443 Rows (size 512,824Kb).
   Time taken for entire script: 2.04s.
   ```

These both run fine and fast. The next is almost exactly the same size as the first but takes 40x as long!

1. **DatabaseC**:

   ```
   Table [XI]  29,543 Rows (size 20,880Kb).
   Table [XII] 538,302 Rows (size 68,000Kb).
   Time taken for entire script: 44.38s.
   ```

I cannot work out why this is taking so long. I have used SQL Server Profiler and the Performance Monitor, but I cannot nail-down the reason for this massive change in performance.

The query being used to do the update is dynamic and is shown at the bottom of this question - it is large due the explicit reference to the required columns. My question is; what could be causing this inordinate increase in execution time?

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

*SQL:*

```
DECLARE @DbName NVARCHAR(128);
SET @DbName = (SELECT TOP 1 [DbName] 
               FROM [IPACostAdmin]..[TmpSpecialOptions]);
DECLARE @FilterSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @FilterSql = (SELECT TOP 1 [AdditionalSQL] 
                  FROM [IPACostAdmin]..[TmpSpecialOptions]);
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL1 = 
    'INSERT INTO [' + @DbName + ']..[Episode] 
        ([Fields1], ..., [FieldN])'; 
SET @SQL2 = 
'SELECT 
     [Fields1], ..., [FieldN] 
FROM [B1A] ' + @FilterSql + ';'; 
SET @SQL = @SQL1 + @SQL2;
EXEC(@SQL);
GO
```

Note: I am splitting the dynamic SQL into `@SQL1` and `@SQL2` for clarity. Also note that I have not shown all columns due to space and the fact that it would largely be redundant.

*Edit1.*

*1. The databases are on the same server.*

*2. The database files, including logs are in the same directory on the same drive.*

*3. There are no primary/foriegn keys or constraints set up on the source databases (DatabaseA/B/C) or the data warehouse database at the time of this `INSERT INTO`.*

*Edit2. I have ran the above query in management studio and it took 5s!?*

*Edit3. I have added a temporary `CLUSTERED INDEX` in a hope that this would assist this query, this has not helped either.*

Comment: Why do you use a two level dynamic query? I think only one execute would be enought. Do you have any specific reason for this?

Comment: Did you try to get the value of @SQL and execute it yourself to see how much time it takes?

Comment: I do. This script is precompiled into a database of SQL queries... Actually looking at it now, I think my reason for this is now gone, and I could step the level of the dynamics SQL down. However, this is not the cause of my problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @PraVn I have, but I have not run analysis on this as yet. I don't think my inability to retrieve any decent analysis on this problem will be changed by running this query as stand alone. Note, that the query obtained from `@SQL` is okay for the third database and is the same as that for the preceeding two...

Comment: @PraVn I have just run the query in management studio, using break point etc. and it ran in 5 seconds!? I clearly did not do this right before. This make this evenmore interesting.

Comment: I have redueced the level of the SQL and updated the question... The query is still running so this has not solved the issues (as we expect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a `DELETE` query being run before a preceeding `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX` query had time to update the entire table. The solution was to use the `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` keywords. This forces SQL Server to finish the indexing *before* attampting anyother operations.

Note, that this problem is only likely to arise when following a `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX` query with a dynamic SQL statement that modifies the existing tabel.

I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Some information would be great to know:

1: Databases are on the same server?

2: The db file and the logfile is on the same drive in case of A and C?

(Once I had a problem with two database where one of them was on an SSD drive and the other one in a HDD. That was a problem of reading the data)

3: DB statistics about fragmentation? (Tables has no constraints, but Indexes are defined?)

Comment: Ahh, I am running with SSDs, and a 1TB external HD. But, all the databases being accessed are on the HD... This is also happening on different machines - with different configurations so I suspect it is an data issue but I have no idea how to progress.